# How to do to increase the fragment in the fragment

Tags: android, button, fragment

I want to use this button to increase the fragment in the fragment above.

Please tell me how to do it.
Thank you, friends.

My idea is to do an operation interface switch
A screen five buttons were linked to a different screen
Different screen has five buttons

Here is my source code.
Remarks error code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.indexomune, container, false);
    Button USER = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.USER);
    USER.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager user = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction User = user.beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment = user.findFragmentById(R.id.USSER);
                if (fragment == null) {
                    String title = "Fragment A";
                    usermenu TAT = new usermenu(title);
                    user.add(R.id.USSER, TAT);
                    //The method add(int, usermenu) is undefined for the type FragmentManager
                    user.addToBackStack(null);
                    //The method addToBackStack(null) is undefined for the type FragmentManager
                    user.commit();
                    //The method commit() is undefined for the type FragmentManager
                }

        }


    });
    return view;

}
```

Comment: You have two variables named user.. one is 'user' the other is 'User'. Try naming your variables something indicative of what they are so you don't have this problem.. Like: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

Comment: The problem is that you should be using 'User' for add/addToBackStack/commit

Comment: Thank you for your help
I already know how to do it
First you have to read familiar use
And you can not be in increased fragment in the fragment inside
But you can cover fragment in the fragment above up